# batch convert geojson to shapefile

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, convert

I have a directory full of geojson files that I need to convert to shapefiles for editing in QGIS.  As far as I have searched, there are no resources in GIS StackExchange that explain how to do this from a  *geojson* .

The output should be shapefiles, named exactly the same as the geojson, in a separate directory. Can anyone recommend the best method to do this programmatically in Python or in other software?